# Complexe macOS command with suprocess Popen - Python

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

I want to call this terminal command on macOS in python `lsappinfo info -only name lsappinfo front`. It returns the name of the [current foreground application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515436/how-to-get-current-foreground-applications-name-or-pid-in-os-x).

Here is how I understand the command:

- `lsappinfo` return information about running apps
- `info` allows to select specific data
- `lsappinfo front` select the foreground process
- `name` select
  the name of the process only

And here is my current code:

```
import subprocess

sub = subprocess.Popen(['lsappinfo', 'info', '-only', 'name', '`lsappinfo front`'])
out, err = sub.communicate()
print(err)
print(out)
```

But I get:

```
>>> None
>>> None
```

The expected output of the command is

```
"LSDisplayName"="AppName"
```

I succeed using `os.system()` but I want to achieve it with `subprocess` since it's the recommended way and I want to store the output. Does someone know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried what suggest this response? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873354/19934610

Comment: I get ```0``` as output with the ```call``` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works:

```
cmd1 = ['lsappinfo', 'front']
name = subprocess.run(cmd1, shell=False, capture_output=True).stdout.decode('utf-8').strip("\n")
cmd2 = ['lsappinfo', 'info', '-only', "name", name]
out2 = subprocess.run(cmd2, shell=False, capture_output=True)
print(out2.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip("\n"))
```

`subprocess` has issues with bash evals (the backticks). Same with `grep`.
You need to do it in 2 steps in your python code. Bit of a workaround but it works.

Output:

```
$ python test.py  
"LSDisplayName"="Code"
```

(Edit: added the strip for the `\n` at the end.)
Use this in a function and you're good to go.
Note: It returns "Code" for me since I ran it in VSCode, which was in the foreground at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

did you check if is needed any special permission?

what is the output if you write your command in a .sh file, and then execute the command as `["./{myscript}.sh"]` or so  (remember to add +x perms)?

Comment: I have a permission error: ```PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied```. What is +x perms?

Comment: your script needs to get execution permissions; 

`chmod +x {script}.sh` to grant it; 

as far i get, seems like it's most like a permission issue

Comment: Oh yes, I still have the same error after giving the .sh script executable permission, but I manage to get the expected output by calling the script with ```sudo```

Answer (score 0):

The command you actually want to run is:

```
lsappinfo info -only name $(lsappinfo front)
```

which calls `lsappinfo front` to get the ASN of the front process and then passes the result to a second call to `lsappinfo` to get the name of that process.

The key issue here is that the **shell** calls the two processes for you, so you would have to use the shell in your Python `subprocess` call to do the same... or you would have to do a second `subprocess` call per @Remzinho.

The single step method is:

```
import subprocess as sp

res = sp.run('lsappinfo info -only name $(lsappinfo front)', shell=True)
```

---

Note that backticks are deprecated and `$(...)` should be preferred. The latter, newer method is also nestable.

```
lsappinfo info -only name `lsappinfo front`    # worse
lsappinfo info -only name $(lsappinfo front)   # better
```